# Extract content from MediaWiki API call (XML, cURL)

Tags: php, parsing, curl, mediawiki, xml-parsing

URL:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=text&page=Lost_(TV_series)&format=xml
```

This outputs something like:

```
<api><parse><text xml:space="preserve">text...</text></parse></api>
```

How do I get just the content between **`<text xml:space="preserve">`** and **`</text>`**?

I used **`curl`** to fetch all the content from this URL. So this gives me:

```
$html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
```

What's the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse it. Do it like this:

```
//you already have input text in $html
$html = '<api><parse><text xml:space="preserve">text...</text></parse></api>';

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('text');

//display what you need:
echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

This outputs:

> text...